JSON operators syntax (::json) in JPA native query
I have a query works perfectly with postgresql
SELECT json_build_object('type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(geo.*)::json))
FROM (SELECT t.track_id, p.video_id, ST_MakeLine(p.location)
      FROM point as p inner join track as t on p.video_id = t.video_id
      group by p.video_id, t.track_id
      order by track_id) as geo;

But it doesn't work with JPA native query
@Query(value = "SELECT json_build_object('type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(g.*)::json)) " +
            "FROM (SELECT t.track_id, p.video_id, ST_MakeLine(p.location) " +
            "FROM point as p inner join track as t on p.video_id = t.video_id " +
            "group by p.video_id, t.track_id " +
            "order by track_id) as g",
            nativeQuery = true)


ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"


Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT json_build_object('type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(g.*):json)) FROM (SELECT t.track_id, p.video_id, ST_MakeLine(p.location) FROM point as p inner join track as t on p.video_id = t.video_id group by p.video_id, t.track_id order by track_id) as g] [ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
Position: 93] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

Can anyone help please?

JPA is poor at handling the colon symbols (:). Either escape them as in the answer of saddam.ya below or use SQL standard cast(ST_AsGeoJSON(g.*) as json)

Does this answer your question? Query generated by Hibernate is incorrect for JSON type, How to use '::' in spring boot?

For json, function-like cast syntax also works: json(st_asgeojson(g.*)). If you like the double-colon ::json for its brevity, function-like cast costs you the exact same amount of keystrokes.

You should escape each of the : character using , so that :: becomes \\:\\:, then everything will work:
@Query(value = "SELECT json_build_object('type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(g.*)\\:\\:json)) " +
            "FROM (SELECT t.track_id, p.video_id, ST_MakeLine(p.location) " +
            "FROM point as p inner join track as t on p.video_id = t.video_id " +
            "group by p.video_id, t.track_id " +
            "order by track_id) as g",
            nativeQuery = true)


Using CAST() in your SQL statement is much cleaner way to cast than using the old school PostgreSQL :: syntax.
